# Issue in fetching record from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a field name "date" datatype "char" and value in thid field is "04-08-2011 04:47:08 EDT"
 but when i want to fetch the records from our data base basis on date like

```
select * from table_name where date="04-08-2011 04:47:08 EDT"
```

but i dont get any result for this query,any one can help me

Comment: maybe field too short and some data truncated ?

Comment: maybe you get some error try mysql_error()

Comment: although the manual says it is allowed as an unquoted identifier, `date` is a mysql keyword. Maybe try adding backticks (`) around it to escape the field name.

Comment: @RiaD Thanks for replay me, let me see

Comment: @Jonathan Kuhn thanks for replay me ,let me see

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not use a regular datetime field?

Comment: Consider reproducing your dataset, as a set of DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `LIKE` statement, because if your field has X chars and you insert X-3 chars, the 3 left chars are filled with spaces, so modify your query to be like:

```
select * from table_name where date LIKE "04-08-2011 04:47:08 EDT%"
```

EDIT: date is a field type in MySQL, so this query isn't valid. If your field is 'date', you need to put it between ``, so the query will be like this:

```
select * from table_name where `date`="04-08-2011 04:47:08 EDT"
```

Comment: This is not good advise, you'll be carrying white space overhead in the database for no reason at all. You'll then be using a more expensive query to find the data. Anyway, as mentioned he is actually using `varchar` not `char`.

Comment: Indeed, I just read the comment, and also realised about the `date`, it's a reserved word.

Comment: @Ivan its working on ,date LIKE "04-08-2011 04:47:08 EDT%",
can you tell what is the issue over there

Comment: @Dasarthi Swain: the problem is that `DATE` is a keyword and should not be used as a field name. It is a keyword used for example when creating the database scheme, as it's a field type.

Comment: @lvan hi, problem is not in DATE, the problem in date format, in database by default date format will be 'Y-m-d H:i:s', so we need to convert the date format to 'Y-m-d H:i:s' format and set in query than it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the datatype `char` then any characters that are under the set length of the column will be right padded with spaces.

e.g.

[char](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html)(30) would pad like so:

```
04-08-2011 04:47:08 EDT     <-- spaces up to arrow
```

Use a date datatype or varchar (if you must).

---

In response to comment:

Have you run this query from phpMyAdmin? If so, does it return any rows, if not, try.

Comment: hello @Prisoner sorry i use varchar but it still i am not getting any result